# How to properly assign php array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

1) On head section where javascript is,  I have the following

```
var chartData =[];
...

// generate some random data which I need to change to php array
generateChartData();
...

chart.dataProvider = chartData;
...

function generateChartData() {

            var firstDate = new Date();
            firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);

            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

                var PROCNT = Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 100;
                var FAT = Math.round(Math.random() * 8) + 100;
                var CHOCDF = Math.round(Math.random() * 1) + 80;
                var glucose = Math.round(Math.random() * 1) + 110;
                var albumine = Math.round(Math.random() * 2) + 102;
                var creatinine = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 70;
                var Na = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 103;
                var K = Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 110;
                var Ca = Math.round(Math.random() * 2) + 83;


                chartData.push({
                   date: newDate,
                   Protein: PROCNT,
                    Fats: FAT,
                    Carbo: CHOCDF,
                    Glucose: glucose,
                    Albumine: albumine,
                    Creatinine: creatinine,
                    Sodium: Na,
                    Potasium: K,
                    Calcium: Ca
                });
            }
        }
```

This works Ok with this random data and it is displayed in proper way, but I need to make the graphic with certain mysql query I have after son joins, so

2) On my php program after certain user actions I have the following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

             $date=$row[1];
             $PROCNT=$row[2];
             $FAT=$row[3];
             $CHOCDF=$row[4];
             $glucose=$row[5];
             $albumine=$row[6];
             $creatinine=$row[7];
             $Na=$row[8];
             $K=$row[9];
             $Ca=$row[10];

             $new=array_splice($row,1,-10);

             $chartData_1 = implode(', ', $new); 

$pass="date: $date, Protein: $PROCNT, Fats: $FAT, "
                    ."Carbo: $CHOCDF, "
                    ."Glucose: $glucose, "
                    ."Albumine: $albumine, "
                    ."Creatinine: $creatinine, "
                    ."Sodium: $Na, "
                    ."Potasium: $K, "
                    ."Calcium: $Ca";

         $json = json_encode($pass); 
                  echo $json;
```

... Then I refresh screen and the datagrid I have ... to get new grid and the graphic

3) So my $json looks OK:

```
"date: 2012-10-10, Protein: 10.6532, Fats: 45.5899, Carbo: 6.83007, Glucose: 120, Albumine: 3.9, Creatinine: 1.2, Sodium: 15, Potasium: 22, Calcium: 21"
```

4) Where do I need to assign $json to javascripot chartData array and how?

I have tried everything I have found on inet, but can get it to work and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am not a programmer so clear explanation will be even more appreciated.

My program makes a query, displays a grid, and after the grid the graphic. We wait some actions of user, so on certain selections, we make what is on step 2 making other queries and displaying the results on a graphic, so first time graphic does not have data, but after grid display and user actions, we try to fill chartData array on javascript and display graphic, but "how and where to send such php array to javascript to display the graphic?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't encode array directly to json with (exemple)

```
$myKeys = array('date', 'Protein', 'Carbo' /*, ... */);
$myValues = array(date('m/d/Y'), 25.3, 32 /*, ... */);
$myData = array_combine($myKeys, $myValues);

$json = json_encode($myData);
echo $json; // {"date":"10\/18\/2012","Protein":25.3,"Carbo":32}
```

A rapid way to integrate:

```
    <?php
    // your code that generate $result
    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* ... your js ... */

    function generateChartData() {

    /* ... */

    <?php
    // a part of php to fill chartData
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {             

        // build data from $row 
        $json = json_encode($data);
        echo "chartData.push($json)\n";
    }
    ?>
    /* ... end of generateChartData... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but a) $json goes with all quotes (which is worst that I had I just had " at the beginning and end of full string) Now is this: {"date":"2012-10-10","Protein":"10.6532","Fats":"45.5899","Carbo":"6.83007","Glucose":"120","Albumine":"3.9","Creatinine":"1.2","Sodium":"15","Potasium":"22","Calcium":"21"} and b) Main question is after having the proper $json what to do with that (how to send it to javascript array chartData and where in the program ?. Thanks

Comment: I missed your comment, I have added a rapid way

Comment: Thanks again, but $json is not being recognized for some reason I don't understand. What you said is coded here: http://kancerlabs.com/nt32a/mff.php and I would like to behave as here (with random data): http://kancerlabs.com/nt32a/graphics.php I would be able to paid to solve this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Parse your `JSon` with php and for each element in your json add it to your `javascript array` :

```
var array = new Array(<?= $element1; ?>, <?= $element2; ?>);
```

Comment: I understand that OP wants to assign PHP array to javascript, not the other way around.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was javascript to php

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var yourarray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
</script>
```